# Counting values in a column if a certain value exists in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a Summary tab in my spreadsheet that will summarize info from another tab. Primarily, the parent tab is a list of tasks, status of the tasks (open or complete), and the persons assigned to those tasks.

I'm wanting to create a Summary tab that will show for a specific assignee how many tasks they have assigned to them, how many of those tasks are completed and how many are still open.

I was able to calculate the first column with a simple `COUNTIF` formula which returned a count if a particular task was assigned to a specific user.

Now I want to only return a count for that user if those tasks are open (thus not including the completed tasks in the count).

The formula I've been working with is:

```
=COUNTIF(('Sheet1'!M1:M165,"John")*IF('Sheet1'!H1:H165,"Completed",""))

M = Assignee Column
H = Status Column
```

Can someone help?

Comment: you have a couple of mistakes in your formula. E.g.: COUNTIF(range, criteria) - you wrote: `COUNTIF((range,criteria)*IF())`. `IF(criteria,<value to return if criteria is true>,<value to return if criteria is false>)` - you wrote: `IF(range,criteria,"")`. Besides really `COUNTIFS` is the correct function here as shown in the answer you really need to take care of correct use of formulae otherwise you won't get the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `COUNTIFS`, which allows to use multiple ranges and multiple conditions without making the formula statement too complicated.

The general format is the below:

```
COUNTIFS( criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2, ... criteria_range_n, criteria_n] )
```

Which for your case be would like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!H:H,"<>completed",Sheet1!M:M,"John")
```

The `<>` in Excel is the same as not equal to. 
More examples of COUNTIFS  with different criteria [can be found here](http://www.watterson-software.com/excel-using-countif-and-countifs/).

Comment: Hmm...getting close.  Whenever I hit enter after inputting the code, a window pops up asking me to select a file.  When I choose the same file, I get the #VALUE error.

Comment: If possible can I have a screenshot of the summary page with the formula please. Also are you using the function wizard to insert the formula?

Comment: The code is actually working now.  Primarily, I think it was a problem with my computer.  When I rebooted, several things started working in Excel and other programs that were acting odd before. Thanks for your help!